# What is “primitive recursive arithmetic with bounded transfinite induction”?

Tags: mathematical-logic

Via @Conifold:

> “Primitive recursive arithmetic with bounded transfinite induction that Gentzen used to prove consistency of Peano arithmetic is incomparable in expressiveness or deductive strength to Peano arithmetic, neither stronger nor weaker.”

(Wanted to elaborate on this but no time just yet.)

Comment: Well, there's a Wikipedia page on [Primitive recursive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic), while transfinite induction has a [Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343527/principle-of-transfinite-induction), an [ELI5](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/416atj/can_someone_eli5_transfinite_induction/). If you asked them to explain and they didn't, then Google should probably be the next place you turn (and only after that should you ask on a Q&A).

Comment: Wikipedia has articles on [primitive recursive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic), typically considered with ordinary quantifier-free induction, and on [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). "Bounded" means up to the ordinal ε0 needed in Gentzen's consistency proof. Aside from Wikipedia's sketch, there is a more [detailed discussion of his proof in SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/#GentConsProo). The more technical questions about his system and proof are probably best asked on MathSE.

Comment: Tait[[??](https://home.uchicago.edu/~wwtx/PRA2.pdf)] is a good historical overview with a section on the relationship between PRA and Kant (of all people!). I'm not sure that PRA and PA are *technically* incomparable since they both have proof-theoretic ordinals (and all ordinals are comparable...), although there might be another technical sense of comparability/commensurability such that PRA and PA are "not on the same list."